# Missing src folder with YARN or NPM package install

Tags: npm, leaflet, package, yarnpkg

Creating a simple package.json

```
yarn init

{
  "name": "freedraw",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Adding leaflet-freedraw dependency:

```
yarn add leaflet-freedraw

{
  "name": "freedraw",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet-freedraw": "^2.13.0"
  }
}
```

The installed node module only contains this:

```
/dist
package.json
LICENSE
README.md
```

There sould also be the source folder installed:

```
/src
```

The devs from freedraw say the /src folder should also be there.

I'm using a lot of packages and I get the /src folder everywhere except here. Same happens with `npm`.

Comment: You're not asking a question. I guess you should make your complaints at https://github.com/Wildhoney/Leaflet.FreeDraw/issues , and/or send a pull request regarding https://github.com/Wildhoney/Leaflet.FreeDraw/commit/3b82125994e9676ea018d67bf04a679934bbf5e8 .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Comment: The question was already asked at freedraw like I wrote. The answer was it should work. So I'm asking here again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There sould also be the source folder installed

There is no obligation for an author to also publish the src on npm.

As pointed out by Ivan, it looks like the author *did* configure their package to publish *only* files in the "dist" folder: (that might be a mistake on their part)

Extract from `package.json`:

```
{
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
}
```

https://github.com/Wildhoney/Leaflet.FreeDraw/commit/3b82125994e9676ea018d67bf04a679934bbf5e8

npm doc for `package.json` "files" field:

> The optional `files` field is an array of file patterns that describes the entries to be included when your package is installed as a dependency. File patterns follow a similar syntax to `.gitignore`, but reversed: including a file, directory, or glob pattern (`*`, `**/*`, and such) will make it so that file is included in the tarball when it’s packed. Omitting the field will make it default to `["*"]`, which means it will include all files.

https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-json.html#files

Comment: OK, thanks. I was wondering because he said he tested it and could not find a problem. I will try to let him change this.

Answer (score 1):

We are facing a similar issue, and are missing the `src/` sub-directory when running a global install of an NPM package from our private NPM registry.

There is nothing referenced in the `.npmignore` or `.gitignore` files, and we are even explicitly referencing the `src/` sub-directory in `files` block in the `package.json`:

```
{
...
  "main": "./bin/cli.js",
  "bin": {
    "app_name": "./bin/cli.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/cli.js"
  },
  "files": [
    "bin",
    "test",
    "src",
    "package.json"
  ],
...
}
```

Interestingly the install also fails to install the `test` sub-directory, and moving the entry point to the `src/` sub-directory results in it failing to install at all with the following error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '...node_modules/@private_registry/app_name/src/cli.js
```

Comment: This isn't an answer... but did you find a solution?